# On a button tap about 60 plus times My iPad App getting slow and then crashed finally

Tags: ios, ipad, profiling, instruments, cpu-usage

On Start my app is working just Perfect, after some time its getting slow and more slow....

**it takes about 8 to 10 seconds to respond the action, and finally it is crashed**
 I don't know why this all is happening.
 I am using a collectionview on uiviewcontroller, all its content views are created in custome cell class.

after using Instruments to test on iPAd 2, took these screen shoots.

now what should I do.?? have you seen any problem here...???

**here is Plus button in UICollectionView Cell to perform an action, on button tap time is increasing randomly and reached to 300000+ ms**

**Note that ---> Main thread shows 0.0 ms**

**What that mean....????**

please guide me in right direction

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is complete code of this method

```
 -(void)btnPlus:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:myCollection];
btnIndex = [myCollection indexPathForItemAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
MyCell *cell = (MyCell*)[myCollection cellForItemAtIndexPath:btnIndex];
NSString *newCode = [productID objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row];
newQty = cell.cellQty.text;
if ([updatedCodes containsObject:newCode])
{
    //NSLog(@"Object Already Exist...");
    for (i = 0; i < [updatedCodes count]; i ++)
    {
        if ([newCode isEqualToString:[updatedCodes objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            qnty = [newQty integerValue];
            qnty = qnty + 1;
            cell.cellQty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", qnty];
            newQty = cell.cellQty.text;
            [updatedQty replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newQty];
        }
    }
    if (![indexPaths containsObject:btnIndex])
    {
        [indexPaths addObject:btnIndex];
    }
    prdID = [productID objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row];
    [self UpdateProduct]; // Open DB SQlite DB Connection and update Table Record and Close Connection.
} 
else
{
    [updatedCodes addObject:newCode];
    qnty = [newQty integerValue];
    qnty = qnty + 1;
    cell.cellQty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", qnty];
    newQty = cell.cellQty.text;
    [updatedQty addObject:newQty];
    if (![indexPaths containsObject:btnIndex])
    {
        [indexPaths addObject:btnIndex];
    }
    prdID = [productID objectAtIndex:btnIndex.row];
    [self BuyProduct]; // Open DB SQlite DB Connection and update Table Record and Close Connection.
}
[myCollection reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths]; // I think problem is here.
}
```

I think problem is at **reload on specific index paths in CollectionView** again and again is causing the problem as it takes 91% of time to execute. am I right..???

Where should / can I improve my code?

Comment: That's probably why you should try to avoid "testing" your apps in the simulator. Running the app on the oldest possible devices, like iPad 2 should reveal all of your problems.

Comment: @SergiusGee plz chek my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have very heavy activity on the main thread (thread 1 in the diagram above) which would tie up with the app becoming unresponsive. That would seem to be more of a problem than memory usage.

You need to profile your app in instruments to get more detail - there's a button right there in your screenshot. Use the time profiler and it will tell you which methods are taking up all your time. These will need to be optimised and/or moved to background threads, but without detail from instruments and code, there's no more help to offer.

Comment: thanks for your respose, will you like to tell me how to use time profile? where it is?

Comment: I did tell you. Click the button that says "profile in instruments"

Comment: So, on the top screenshot of instruments, you can double-click the name of the method and it will open a view on your code showing which are the lines taking up the time.

Comment: yes i tried, it showed for some line of code 10%, 11% some time 0.2% or 0.8%, and on some lines of code showed 50%, 67% and at one of line it was 100%.

Comment: what that mean, i think 67% or 100% is bad , so what should i do

Comment: You'll need to put the code into your question, with the percentages for the lines. The percentage is just how much time of that particular method was spent on one particular line, so even if the method is really well optimised it will still add up to 100% :)

Comment: which method should i post here, there are alot of methods on this viewController and there are several lines of Code with % sign like 67%, 50% or 100% in these methods.

Comment: CellForItemAtIndexPath (the top one on your instruments trace) would be a good start.

Comment: i have update the whole question plz review it and suggest me what should i do now.